# How can I make button under link?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add buttons inside Link and don't know how can I do this.
I am give buttons z-index: 99 but it didn't work.
It need to be link but when you click on Button link doesn't work but button function have to work.

HTML

```
<ul>
  <a href="https://www.google.com/">
    <li>
      <h1>Test</h1>
      <div class="buttons">
        <button>X</button>
      </div>
    </li>
  </a>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul{
  a{
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  
  li{
    position: relative;
    list-style-type: none;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: 200px;
  }
  
  .buttons{
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
  }
}
```

Example in codepen : https://codepen.io/Orest97/pen/XWjZYzg

Comment: Could you explain what result you're trying to achieve ? Currently you seem to be on the wrong path.

Comment: I wnat that buttons on top rigth corner of link and if you click on button, the link should doesnt work

Comment: Links cannot contain buttons and buttons cannot contain links. It's invalid HTML

Comment: @John what if you set the CSS property of a `span` to be a `display: block`? There are cases where this will happen. I get what you're saying, but to say "never" is not exactly correct (bad markup practices aside).

Comment: @disinfor It is completely legitimate to set an inline element to be `display: block` and I have done this on occasion when appropriate though you should not do the reverse.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you should structure your HTML to achieve the desired result:

```css
ul{
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 25px 80px;
  background: gray;
  display: block;
}

button{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="https://www.google.com/">Test</a>
    <button>X</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```